# Android application to allow user map his location

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I ask user to enter his location(text) and call Google web service to find out geocodes and then display on map.

Now I also want the user to fine tune his location by moving the marker on the map.

How can this be done?

Rgds,
Sapan

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this source http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~financisto-dev/financisto/trunk/view/head:/src/ru/orangesoftware/financisto/activity/LocationActivity.java at `LocationOverlay` inner class in particular